# What is wrong with my answer

Tags: discussion

OP asked for a feature that I hate. I gave him a link of mouse that exactly has that feature.

How the hell it isn't answering the question?

[Mouse with separate scroll wheel and middle button](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/740/mouse-with-separate-scroll-wheel-and-middle-button/5916?noredirect=1#comment9013_5916)

summary:
http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/mice?filters=3374

Every single one has that stupid feature where I can't click the middle button, which is exactly what you want. They have another middle button but I like to use that for gesture.

Maybe I should mention that the feature name is hyper fast scrolling. Also I have filtered logitech product based on that feature.

I already added another answer that is more correct.

The problem is that there are several products that do match what the user want. The one I am using is mx anywhere 2. Even though many says master is better.

Here's the issue. I narrowed it down to 2 product. One is the one I actually use. Another is much more expensive but better. How the hell I was supposed to know which one is better for OP?

Why is it wrong not to recommend one single product if there are indeed many products that qualify?

Also the question problem is that they accidentally click the middle button. When the scroll wheel is clicked it doesn't register the middle click. So his problem is solved. Clicking the scroll would simply switch to fine scrolling. It's not even a click. It's more of mode switch.

I noticed that a person need to press half centimeter to switch to fine scrolling. I didn't notice that. So yea, no way of accidental click there.

Why don't you let the OP review my answer rather than censoring it? I think my recommendation would be useful for OP. If there are better mouses others would have answered it.

If you have issues with my answers you can just downvote or put comments. I think that issue can be solved more easily rather than deleting answer. I can then update my answer based on comments and what OP truly wants.

If you delete answers, OP doesn't even know someone is answering. His question is not answered. How can he found his mouse?

If my answer doesn't perfectly answer what op wants, he can comment, other people will recommend other mouses. He's "going somewhere".

I think what I recommend is already a very good start.

Comment: Furthermore, that is, in fact, not a separate middle button but a button that does something else altogether, so your answer would be irrelevant no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the entire text of your answer:

> I actually hate that feature.
>
> That being said, look here
>
> http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/mice?filters=3374
>
> Every single one has that stupid feature where I can't click the middle button, which is exactly what you want. They have another middle button but I like to use that for gesture.
>
> I am actually looking for the opposite. I want clickable middle button. He he he he

If we remove all the extraneous cruft and irrelevant content, that boils down to this:

> Look here
>
> http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/mice?filters=3374
>
> These mice have the feature you want.

which doesn't by any objective standard meet the [answer quality requirements](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/60/8) that we have on this site.

I also left you a comment explaining why I deleted it, which is basically a short version of this post:

> Answers need to include some detail about why your recommended product is right for the OP. Since this doesn't, I'm deleting it.

Your answer needs to:

- recommend a *single* product (preferably one you've had experience with, rather than one you spent 10 seconds Googling)
- in *detail* - explain why that product is the correct choice

before it can be undeleted.

Comment: These mice have the feature you want. Every single one has that stupid feature where I can't click the middle button, which is exactly what you want. They have another middle button but I like to use that for gesture. In what way it's unclear. It's exactly what the OP ask?

Comment: Oh only 1 product? Yes I have experience with the product. I have MX anywhere mouse

Comment: @JimThio I never said it was unclear.

Comment: OP said they want a mouse without clickable scroll. I told them the mouse I point has that exact same stupid feature. Their scroll is not clickable. There is no other answer to that.

Comment: I hate that feature and I think that's a very stupid feature but that's what OP wants and the mice are otherwise good. My answer match the question. That means it's a good answer

Comment: Okay it lacks detail. Is that the problem? I just wonder what more detail I can add for "no clickable scroll". I thought americans like to the point short answers.

Comment: In what ways exactly does my answer fail http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/59/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality/60#60

Comment: And why it has to be a single product? Other answers have many other products

Comment: @JimThio You're not listening. I did not delete your answer for not answering the question. I acknowledge that it answers the question. However, it recommends a list of products, which isn't something we want answers to do. It also gives basically no detail. If you've had experience with *one* of those products, detail your experience with it. If there are other answers recommending a list of products, link me to them and I will deal with them or explain why I don't need to.

Comment: Okay, Anyway. Wy don't you answer the question? No one else does? I'll make another shot following your suggestions.

Comment: I haven't answered it because I don't have an appropriate recommendation.

Comment: I put some answer up. Does this one meet your criteria?

Comment: Okay where is the rule saying that it has to be a single product?

Comment: Looks like I miss that. You said that you want a single product recommendation even though many products fit the criteria. Is there a link somewhere that says it should be a single product? Is this just your own opinion or is it a consensus?

Comment: this was an entertaining read.