# Is this site going to die in beta?

Tags: discussion

I posted as a new user today [Memory upgrade suggestions by Crucial](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9016/memory-upgrade-suggestions-by-crucial) .

Only 2 views for the question so far in 10 hours (Normally this should be reached to more people at least from the first post review queue and newest and active questions tabs? ) - means less active users?

No [healthy signs](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations) either to be seen even after 930 days in beta.

Or any other reason why my question was not reached to many?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very true that the participation stats of this site aren't the highest on the network. (They're also not the lowest, though.) However, that's not a problem, nor does it mean we're going to die in beta, and [this is why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/262823).

Essentially, **stats don't matter**. What matters is being able to provide quality answers to quality questions, and being able to keep the site moderated.

In terms of quality, we have strict quality guidelines for [questions](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/8) and [answers](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/60/8); those are well enforced both by the community and by the diamond moderators. In terms of moderation, we have three active diamond moderators who are more than capable of handling the small moderation workload this site provides.

So **no**, this site is not going to die in beta any time soon.