# Who should our moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Somehow we've gone two weeks without someone posting this - I'm pretty sure that's a record. I figure that we can start nominating folks so that we're ready to go when we hit public beta in a few weeks.

The following is shamelessly copied, with modifications, from [SR's nomination thread](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67/nominate-temporary-moderators-for-this-site-here):

---

Soon after the site launches into public beta, the Community Team will appoint provisional moderators from this community until the community graduates and is ready to hold its own elections.

**Deep engagement in the community's development** is required for all temporary moderator candidates. All potential candidates must:

> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
>
> Bonus points for:
>
> - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
> - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.
>
> Candidates will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act
>   as provisional Moderators until the community holds formal elections
>   after the Beta period.

### Nominating users to serve as moderators for the beta

For each user that you would like to nominate,

- post an answer containing the URLs to both of the user's **main and meta profiles on this site**
- make your answer **community wiki** (there's a checkbox in the answer form) so that candidates without editing privileges can edit in their acceptance
- optionally, link to the user's **Area 51 profile** or a profile from another site, or add a reason why you'd like him/her to moderate during beta
- **self-nominations** (i.e. posting your own profiles) are allowed *and encouraged*
- post each user as a separate answer, and add multiple answers if you wish to nominate multiple users

Additionally, if someone nominates *you*, please **edit the answer** to indicate your approval (or declination). Optionally, add a paragraph or two about yourself.

If you downvote a particular nomination, you are encouraged to **share why** you did so in the comments, though you are not required to do so. Optionally, you may do the same for upvotes.

For more information, see [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Answer (score 18):

### [Undo](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/1)

[image]

[image]


[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1703573.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1703573)

I would moderate this site in much the same way I moderate [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/46/undo):

- Nuke the low quality answers
- Close the low quality questions
- Leave a comment inviting the user to read the guidelines and post a new answer or edit their question.

Rinse, wash, repeat. It's worked out well on SR ([we're graduating!](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/46)), and the community here [approves of the approach for answers](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-have-sr-style-quality-guidelines-for-questions-and-answers). If that approval were to change in the future, I wouldn't have any issues being flexible to that. There are great people here  - as of now, I'd approve of any combination of the folks on this page, whether I'm in that group or not. The site's in good hands.

Comment: You're a mod on SR, which could provide us with some good experience modding a similar site. But to ask an awkward question, how does an SR mod make sure that his practices don't leak to HR if they wouldn't benefit the site?

Comment: @ArtOfCode Good question. As a community *member*, I personally hope this site follows in the footsteps of SR in many ways. That said, as a *moderator*, were that to happen, I would enforce whatever the community decides on for policy. We've got a clean(ish) slate with this site, we should do our best to make policies for HR, not copy directly from SR. I've gotten quite good at putting sites in their own little sandboxes after a few years of participating in multiple sites, that can extend to here.

Answer (score 13):

### [Adam](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/155)

[image]


[image]


[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/6279720.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/6279720)

I spend quite a bit of time on this site. I'm currently the [most active user](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287?phase=beta&users=mostactive#tab-top) and the [highest in reputation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287?phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top). Though this isn't a numbers competition, I feel these go to show my dedication.

**Hardware and Such**
I'm very experienced in pretty much everything computers and I work with tons of audio and video equipment every day, so I'm able to provide detailed, helpful recommendations for a wide range of types of hardware. I use my knowledge to give people thorough answers to the questions they ask as often as I can.

**Moderation**
Although I've never had the opportunity to moderate a community on SE, I have lots of experience moderating very large communities on reddit (which I feel is a great start because reddit communities get out of hand so easily). I pride myself on being civil at all times, logical when a problem arises, and responsive to the duties I have. At the same time I like joking around here and there because humor is what keeps a relaxed environment and people happy.

Comment: I am getting 404's on your profiles. It looks like you have an extra `/users` in your links.

Comment: Fixed, @Cfinley

Comment: Copy/paste has failed me again.

Comment: You say that you have experience being a moderator on Reddit, which is great, and I'm sure that many admire that! However, the "forum" is drastically different from SE, to the point where some take offence to when people say that Reddit and SE are similar, or "practically the same thing". If appointed a moderator, how do you think you're moderation tasks will differ from that on Reddit with SE (which, recommendations are already quite different from the normal SE vision)?

Comment: Believe me, I know how drastically different the sites are. Moderating on reddit provides the opportunity to keep order in huge communities but not much more than that. I'm very fond of how SE works, and my current activity goes to show that I'll have no problem putting in time to learn moderation best-practices on SE. I can say for sure that I'm already fond of identifying and dealing with low-quality questions and answers, tag cleanup, and of course communication within the community.

Comment: Correction: as of 2015-10-01, Adam is now the highest rep user.

Comment: Correction correction: there's now a rep dance going on between us.

Answer (score 11):

### [Cfinley](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/60/cfinley)

[image]


[image]

[profile for Cfinley on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/4359143.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/4359143/cfinley)

This guy has a pretty good number of rep, and a fairly high level of participation on meta. From his actions, so far, he cares for this site, and is fairly selfless: he nominates two other potential moderators and doesn't do so for himself.

---

I accept. I am committed to helping this site grow and develop. While I haven't had an account on the SE network for long (~1.5 years), I have been committed to quality. On SuperUser, I only have 1.4K rep, but I have raised 551 [helpful flags](https://superuser.com/users/317198/cfinley?tab=topactivity), 1473 [first post reviews](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/stats), 500 late answer reviews, and 747 [suggested edits approved](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/414136). I am confident that I can help this site reach graduation.

Comment: Quick note: there is an extra upvote from me for this guy :D

Answer (score 10):

### [ArtOfCode](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/8)

[image]

[image]


[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3457374.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/3457374)

He's been helpful on meta ([#2 for meta participation](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/users)), is our [highest reputation user to date](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users), and [already knows where all the shiny buttons are](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/98/artofcode).

---

**I accept** - and thanks for the vote of confidence.

**On the topic** - I'm a sound engineer and general computer-type techie-type person. That's given me a wealth of experience with sound equipment (desks, amps, cables, headphones, mics... you name it), and a fair amount with computing hardware. Said experience is valuable for recommending various bits of sound and computing, and I've used it here already to recommend headphones and talk about desks and sound setups.

**On moderation** - as Undo notes, I'm a moderator over on Open Source, so the learning curve is shallow. My moderation philosophy goes along the lines of "let's all play nice", and I try (and succeed, I think) to be [patient, fair and impartial](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) in my moderation. I've also been patrolling the review queues around here regularly, as I do everywhere.

**Some thoughts** - I've been watching Software Recommendations for some time, and have debated getting more involved there. When Hardware Recommendations came up into beta I got involved here instead, because hardware is nicer to recommend - software, I find, differs greatly in preference, but having the physical experience of hardware is useful in suggesting things to other people.

Comment: I'm leaving a comment so you can `@`-ping me, if you want to ask questions.

Answer (score 9):

### [Andy](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/57)

*I accept. Thank you for the nomination!*

[image]

[image]


[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/63984.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/63984)

Andy's been one of our most active users, both on the main site and on meta. He's also a moderator on Community Building and is extremely active on Meta Stack Exchange. Plus, he's easy to reach in chat on a range of sites, and he knows the Stack Exchange network well.

Answer (score 6):

**[Enderland](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/6/enderland)**

[image]


[image]


[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1042917.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1042917)

Enderland has been a SE member for about 4 years, so he knows how the site works. Enderland is also a mod over at The Workplace. He is currently in the top 5 of the users with the most rep on this site. I believe Enderland would make a great addition to the mod team here.

---

edit: <s>I accept</s>. I withdraw. There are other candidates here who are far more vested in this site than I would be. It would in my opinion be better for the site for them to be moderators than myself.

Answer (score 1):

**[Gilles](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/45/gilles)**

[image]


[image]


[http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/164368.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/164368)

Gilles moderates a few other sites in public beta, so he knows what beta sites need in order to grow. One of those sites is Software Recommendations, which just got the green light to graduate. Currently he sits inside the top ten of users with the most rep on this site.

---

#### Declined

Thank you for the vote of confidence, but I do not intend to spend a lot of time on HR. I don't have enough interest in hardware.

Answer (score 1):

### **[Rubyjunk](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/476/rubyjunk)**

[image: profile for RubyJunk at Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange, Q&A for people seeking specific hardware recommendations]


[image: profile for RubyJunk at Hardware Recommendations Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for people seeking specific hardware recommendations]

I haven't been on this site very, long and haven't moderated others, but I think that I would be an excellent moderator, because this is the site that I participate the most on, to be honest, the only one I participate on. I'm also usually #1 or close to that in the reputation leagues for the month and week. I'm very active on this site.

---

I don't think I'll get elected because we already have mods, but I figure, why not try?

Comment: "but I think that I would be an excellent moderator"    /falls out of chair

Comment: @NZKshatriya Not anymore - I'm no longer active much. This was last year, in case you didn't notice.

Comment: That is not what the reaction was to, and yes I did notice.

Answer (score 0):

**[Peter Zhu](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/912/peter-zhu)**

[image] [image]

I am a hardcore computer software and hardware enthusiast. I enjoy spending my free time tinkering with them, which is why I would be a great candidate for a moderator. Even though I have never moderated before, I believe that I have the time and skills to become a moderator. The amount of free time I have (since I'm only a high school student) allows me to help others with the expertise that I have acquired. I am the number 1 in the monthly reputation leagues for November and December and I will continue to be very active on this site.